# Find explicit form of $y$

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving a differential equation and I get this as a result:
$$\frac{4}{3} \ln x + c= \sin\left( \frac{y^2}{x^2}-1\right) $$

Is this enough as solution? Or how can show the solution in the form of $y=f(x)$

Comment: post tte original equation please

Comment: the equation is correctly solved . I just can't find a way to find the solution in the form y(x)=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From$$\frac43\ln x+c=\sin\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}-1\right),$$you get that$$\frac{y^2}{x^2}=1+\arcsin\left(\frac43\ln x+c\right)$$and therefore that$$y=\pm x\sqrt{1+\arcsin\left(\frac43\ln x+c\right)}.$$